# Create a comment tag functionality in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

How can I create a comment tag functionality in AngularJS.

Actually when a user start adding comment he should be able to tag a user by entering the special character like @ or # and user dropdown should appear and from there he should pick the user to tag him.

Thanks.

Comment: [Mention](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-mention/example/) from [AngularUI collection](https://angular-ui.github.io/) can help you do that

Comment: Hey it is fine.thanks,please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: In your textarea/input setup up a watch function

Step 2: Within the watch function extract the last character from the input value.

Step 3: if the last character is # or @ , open a modal with the list of list of words/terms.

Steps 4: After user selects one or more tags append those tags to the input scope.